# How do you get notes (engagement) for a contact?

Tags: api, hubspot

How do you get notes (engagement) for a contact, using Hubspot API? All I get is this output:

[image: cl.ly/291c2v2g3G1N]

When I get a contact where do I look to get the engagements IDs? I see a lot of things that say engagement that aren't quite actually engagements. When I use those IDs I get the above.

The API says when I get an engagement I should have a body which is the note content. But I don't see how to get an ID that gives me that kind of response. This is what I get from the contacts API that look like they have to do with this, but again those IDs return the above.

[image: cl.ly/0C081U0a1H3s]

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Support, and they've provided me with a 'secret url'

[api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/recent/modified?portalId=](http://api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/recent/modified?portalId=)

The endpoint will return all the engagements sorted by the recently modified date and show the engagement ID.

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

Neither engagements themselves nor the related IDs are fetchable via HubSpot's Contacts API.  Based on public docs, there's no way to retrieve engagement ID values other than creating the item via API to start.

---

**More detail:**
The *notes_last_contacted* value you treat like an ID in your call to the engagements API is not an engagement ID -- its a UNIX time since epoch (in milliseconds).

Additionally it looks like you're attempting to use /contacts/v1/engagements/vid/******* as your endpoint -- according to docs this is not a viable endpoint.

Take a look at the sample the Contact fetched via API here: https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/email/testingapis@hubspot.com/profile?hapikey=demo

Answer (score 0):

There has been some updates since this question was last discussed. They have started providing an engagements API for different types of engagements and an associations API: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/notes and https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/associations

However, I didn't find a way to fetch the associated objects, only there references. After fetching the associations, you have to fetch the additional objects with a separate API. Which is kind of sucks.